# Interfacing Orion and other GEs from fiware and other APIs

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, complex-event-processing

I'm trying to integrate Proton CEP and Mandrill, an email service, mediated by Orion context broker. 
When I was starting to study Orion, I thought that it would be able to communicate directly with CEP, exchanging JSON objects through http. And also that Orion would be able to parse each object to deliver to the correct format understandable by each API.

From the examples and documentation available I was able to understand that another API developed by us should be doing the parsing and mediating the communications between each API.

So I'd like to confirm that this is so and that I'm not missing something. Is Orion indeed unable to customize its outputs?

If confirmed, then I will proceed with development of this mediating API.

Arthur

Edit:
I believe I wasn't clear above about the issue. I hope adding this helps.

Proton CEP recieves through http POST JSON objects, but it only understands the variables if they are in simple format, like {"Name1":"Value1","Name2":"Value2"}, with no arrays or complex struture.

Orion, can comunicate in JSON as well through http, but I can't control the structure of the JSON output. So the result is that CEP wouldn't be able to understand inputs from Orion and process them. The same issue arises with other APIs too. And I'd like to confirm that Orion is indeed unable to custom its output and that this integration needs to be done on our side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find best explanation about connection between CEP and Orion in [latest guides](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_Proactive_Technology_Online_User_and_Programmer_Guide).

User guide's Appendix A specifies steps to establish such a communication (subscription(s) and/or simple publish).

Answer (score 1):

Orion only understands/returns XML and JSON, and with this it is able to communicate with most of the GEs in FIWARE. I can't tell you anything about the Proton CEP, sorry.
To make sure you have interoperability between GEs (and especially other components) a "mediating gateway" will solve the problem, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON format that Orion Context Broker sends in notification conforms to the NGSI10 context management specification. Using a predefined JSON (instead of a custom one) is the best way to ensure that interoperability with other NGSI-compliant software works.

Before doing the NGSI-to-Proton adaptation piece yourself, I'd recomend you to check with Proton development team if there is any existing NGSI connector to their system that you can reuse. You can find contact details [in Proton page at FIWARE catalogue](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/complex-event-processing-cep-proactive-technology-online).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was indeed missing something with CEP. It does support NGSI XML. I was focusing on JSON, and didn't read with proper attention. I will study it and use it.

Comment: Current version of Orion Context Broker (0.23.0) also support XMLs in notifications. Although XML is currently a deprecated encoding for Orion (few people use XML in modern REST APIs nowdays) take it into account just in case it may simplify integration with CEP based on existing connectors.